# Java replace brackets

Tags: java, regex

How can I replace brackets using the replaceAll() method? For example if I have the string `"[][]teststring]]]]"` I want to use replaceAll() to reduce it to "teststring".

Comment: Did you check the Java documentation or APR references?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you only want to get rid of the square brackets:

```
String output = "[][]teststring]]]]".replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
```

I would also suggest you take a look at the [regular expression documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Answer (score 0):

```
return yourWord.replaceAll("\\[","").replaceAll("\\]","")
```

[JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: If you're going to do use two calls, why not use replace instead of replaceAll and avoid the regular expression overhead:
yourWord.replace("[","").replace("]","")